# GoLand IDE cannot recognize Go files, intellisense/code completion not working

Tags: go, ide, jetbrains-ide, goland

I'm trying to write some basic Go file and I don't have any code completion / intellisense when working **only** with go files.

[image: Go file intellisense picture]

Otherwise, when trying to write JS code for example it works great:

[image: JS file intellisense picture]

Any thoughts?

Comment: 1) Does it happen with ANY `.go` files or with that file /file named `main.go` only? 2) Select your `.go` file in the Project View and invoke `View | Quick Documentation` on it. Then show a screenshot of the popup. For whatever reason GoLand does not treat that file as Go file; rather just a plain text. Syntax colors must be coming from Text Mate plugin (that provides basic syntax colors only).

Comment: Users/avior.peretz/GolandProjects/awesomeProject2/main.go
Size: 44 B
Type: textmate
Modified: 18/08/2022, 10:45
Created: 16/08/2022, 17:31

this is the output

Comment: That's #2. What about #1?

Comment: even with other names its not working properly..

Comment: `Settings/Preferences | Editor | File Types`, find the file type for Go files and check if you have *.go` pattern there. If not -- add it. Looks like you have removed it (somehow.. no clues how .. perhaps because of some glitch) or re-assigned it to some another file type (e.g. Text). If still nothing -- show the screenshots of what you have got there.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set some settings like GOPATH and GOROOT in your IDE.
This is a setup process screenshot of an IDE setting.

[image]

[image]

Comment: i even dont have the go branch inside languages & frameworks..

Comment: I think you have direct go settings in goland IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to *Preferences | Editor | File Types*, find *Text* or *File type auto-detected by context* and remove `main.go` from the file name patterns list.